# Error: Invalid Hook Call when navigating to a particular link in react app

Tags: reactjs, firefox

I have been trying to solve this for sometime now. Whenever I navigate to a particular link in react app the console throws an error in firefox. However, when I navigate to the same link in chrome/edge there is no error. I have checked the component where the error is occuring and everything is fine. I am using hooks as they are supposed to be used. Here is the screenshot of the error in firefox:
[image]

How do I remove this error in firefox?

Edit:
Here is the code where the error occurs:

```js
import {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from 'react'
import {
  useParams,
  useNavigate,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'
import {
  FontAwesomeIcon
} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import {
  faTrashCan,
  faEdit
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import Modal from './modal'
import ErrorModal from './errorModal'
import {
  useAuthContext
} from '../hooks/useAuth'
import {
  Remarkable
} from "remarkable"

function SingleBlog() {
  const params = useParams()
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const [blog, setBlog] = useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const {
    user
  } = useAuthContext()
  const md = new Remarkable()

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getSingleBlog() {
      if (!user) {
        setError('You are not logged in.')
        displayError()
        return
      }

      const response = await fetch(`/api/${params.id}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          accepts: 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`,
        },
      })
      const json = await response.json()
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        setError(json.error)
        displayError()
        return
      } else {
        setBlog(json)
      }
    }

    getSingleBlog()
  }, [params.id, user])

  function displayError() {
    if (!document.querySelector('#errorModal')) return
    document.querySelector('#errorModal').classList.remove('scale-0')
    setTimeout(
      () =>
      document.querySelector('#errorModal').classList.add('scale-0'),
      2000
    )
  }

  if (!user || error) {
    return <ErrorModal props = {
      {
        errorName: '401',
        errorMessage: error
      }
    }
    />
  }

  if (blog == null && !error) {
    return ( <
      div className = "flex grow flex-row justify-center items-center" >
      <
      div className = "animate-spin rounded-full h-32 w-32 border-b-2 border-gray-900" > < /div> < /
      div >
    )
  }

  async function handleDelete() {
    const response = await fetch(`/api/${params.id}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: {
        accepts: 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`,
      },
    })

    if (!response.status === '200') {
      return ( <
        >
        <
        h1 >
        Opps!!!There was an error
        while fetching the resource <
        /h1> < /
        >
      )
    } else {
      return navigate('/')
    }
  }

  function handleModal(e) {
    const modal = document.querySelector('#deleteModal')
    modal.classList.toggle('scale-0')
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', x)

    function x(e) {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', x)

      if (e.target.closest('div').id === 'trashCan') return
      if (!modal.contains(e.target)) {
        modal.classList.add('scale-0')
      }
      if (e.target.textContent === 'OK') {
        handleDelete()
      }
      if (e.target.textContent === 'Cancel') {
        modal.classList.add('scale-0')
      }
    }
  }

  return ( <
    >
    <
    div className = "flex flex-col grow" >
    <
    div className = "flex flex-row justify-between items-center" >
    <
    h1 className = "text-xl sm:text-3xl text-red-800 font-bold my-2 sm:my-3" > {
      blog.title
    } <
    /h1> <
    div className = "flex flex-row space-x-5" >
    <
    div id = "trashCan" >
    <
    FontAwesomeIcon icon = {
      faTrashCan
    }
    className = "text-xl sm:text-2xl text-red-500 cursor-pointer"
    onClick = {
      handleModal
    }
    /> < /
    div > <
    Link to = {
      `/${params.id}/edit`
    } >
    <
    div id = "editIcon" >
    <
    FontAwesomeIcon icon = {
      faEdit
    }
    className = "text-xl sm:text-2xl text-gray-800 cursor-pointer" /
    >
    <
    /div> < /
    Link > <
    /div> < /
    div > <
    div className = "flex flex-col grow gap-y-1 p-y-1 flex-wrap" >
    <
    div className = "flex flex-row text-xs" >
    <
    p className = "font-bold text-gray-600" > Author: < /p> <
    p className = "px-3" > {
      blog.author
    } < /p> < /
    div > <
    div className = "flex flex-col sm:flex-row text-xs" >
    <
    div className = "flex flex-row" >
    <
    p className = "font-bold text-gray-600" >
    Created at:
    <
    /p> <
    p className = "px-3 italic" > {
      new Date(blog.createdAt).toLocaleString()
    } <
    /p> < /
    div > <
    div className = "flex flex-row" >
    <
    p className = "font-bold text-gray-600" >
    Last Updated at:
    <
    /p> <
    p className = "px-3 italic" > {
      new Date(blog.updatedAt).toLocaleString()
    } <
    /p> < /
    div > <
    /div> <
    div className = "font-serif text-xl my-2 sm:my-1" >
    <
    p className = "break-all" > {
      blog.body
    } < /p> < /
    div > <
    /div> < /
    div > <
    Modal / >
    <
    />
  )
}

export default SingleBlog
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you give more context about the code?

Comment: Sure, let me add the code where the error occurs.

Comment: @KavianRabbani The error according to firefox occurs at line 10 where I am using useParams hooks.

Comment: Do you have the same issue when using React 17?

Comment: @KavianRabbani Yes, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you're not breaking the rule of hooks. So, I'd assume that your case is one of the two other cases mentioned by React:
https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and React DOM.
2. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app.

Could you check that?

Comment: I am using dedupe and there is no duplication.

Comment: What about version mismatches? What versions of React and React DOM do you have installed?

Comment: "react": "^18.2.0",
 "react-dom": "^18.2.0",

Comment: What about the script tags you mentioned in your question?

Comment: I added them while adding the snippet. I am not using them in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you installed 'react-dom' outside of your project. Check it.

Comment: No. I am using it correctly.